# Show/Hide Specific Items/Elements based on selected Category

Tags: javascript, html

I have couple images inside a div. Each image belongs to a category. I would like to show images of only a single category when that category/group is selected and hide all other images.

So I have several images at the beginning in the category `all` and if choose `blue` I only want the images in blue category.

I thought it was necessary to create an object array containing all the images and give them a category. Then with an `if/else` play on the category number to display. In the end I can't find the desired result. Can you help me, please?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obqqqxrr/16/).

```js
const img1 = `<img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTn1if-yc-9w3onZhlF9j7eOJEbbH7NY9QoQ0wyuAy33WoH-ml" alt="blue">`;
const img2 = `<img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQFjKqjM52gBUsAisUgVSuGrPMi2kgcZ8lv7DfsiZuYx8KCjCSf" alt="red">`;
const img3 = `<img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTuotUTsRgW-MMvhKc1ZwyDQoamkTut4u-V0_h0bCbxAWMl36A9Xg" alt="red">`
const img4 = `<img class="img" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3823/11294769684_5d4b0d1a23_n.jpg" alt="red">`;
const img5 = `<img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27" alt="blue">`;

const color = [
 {img1, category: [0, 1]},
  {img2, category: [0, 2]},
  {img3, category: [0, 2]},
  {img4, category: [0, 2]},
  {img5, category: [0, 1]}
]
//category 1 = all, 2 = bleu and 3 = red.

function showImg(number) {

}
```

```css
.link__color {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.contain {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contain__img {
  margin: 15px;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
  <a onclik="showImg()" class="link__color" href="#">All</a>
  <a onclik="showImg()" class="link__color" href="#">Blue</a>
  <a onclik="showImg()" class="link__color" href="#">Red</a>
</div>

<div class="contain">
  <div class="contain__img">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTn1if-yc-9w3onZhlF9j7eOJEbbH7NY9QoQ0wyuAy33WoH-ml" alt="blue">
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQFjKqjM52gBUsAisUgVSuGrPMi2kgcZ8lv7DfsiZuYx8KCjCSf" alt="red">
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTuotUTsRgW-MMvhKc1ZwyDQoamkTut4u-V0_h0bCbxAWMl36A9Xg" alt="red">
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img">
    <img class="img" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3823/11294769684_5d4b0d1a23_n.jpg" alt="red">
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27" alt="blue">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excuse me, I misspoke. In fact the images that I display, I want what changes according to the category. If I click on the "blue"button, there are only the images that have blue, if I click on red, the images with red and the "all" button all the images.

Comment: are you going to hardcode the images in html or they are going to be pulled dynamically?

Comment: I wish it were dynamic at the end. But for now it's gonna be "hardcore" ahaha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works without creating any category. Just put the image type in **alt** attribute of the image.

```js
function showImg(category) {
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.img');
  elements.forEach(function(el){
    if(category=='all')el.parentNode.style.display='inline';
    else if(el.getAttribute('alt')==category)el.parentNode.style.display='inline';
    else el.parentNode.style.display='none';
  });
}
```

```css
.link__color {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.contain {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contain__img {
  margin: 15px;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
  <a onclick="showImg('all')" class="link__color" href="#">All</a>
  <a onclick="showImg('blue')" class="link__color" href="#">Blue</a>
  <a onclick="showImg('red')" class="link__color" href="#">Red</a>
</div>

<div class="contain">
  <div class="contain__img">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTn1if-yc-9w3onZhlF9j7eOJEbbH7NY9QoQ0wyuAy33WoH-ml" alt="blue" >
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQFjKqjM52gBUsAisUgVSuGrPMi2kgcZ8lv7DfsiZuYx8KCjCSf" alt="red">
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTuotUTsRgW-MMvhKc1ZwyDQoamkTut4u-V0_h0bCbxAWMl36A9Xg" alt="red">
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img">
    <img class="img" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3823/11294769684_5d4b0d1a23_n.jpg" alt="red">
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27" alt="blue">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, that's exactly what I wanted. I thought it was going to be a lot more complicated. Thanks again

Comment: However I don't understand on Edit Fiddle it doesn't work. I tried to modify the querySelector. Nothing to do, I changed the code a little bit, but laughed.

Comment: In fiddle the javascript code is nested inside another function. That's why it doesn't work there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to create a constant variable and assign it again. Make it Simple. Apply common class for the blue and red images. Try to target the `div` based on the classes you applied. Look at the below HTML and Jquery. I have applied the `blue` and `red` classes for the respective images and target the same.

**HTML**

```
<div class="link" id="mainLink">
  <a id="all" class="link__color" href="#">All</a>
  <a id="blue" class="link__color" href="#">Blue</a>
  <a id="red" class="link__color" href="#">Red</a>
</div>

<div class="contain">
  <div class="contain__img blue">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTn1if-yc-9w3onZhlF9j7eOJEbbH7NY9QoQ0wyuAy33WoH-ml" alt="blue">
 </div>

 <div class="contain__img red">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQFjKqjM52gBUsAisUgVSuGrPMi2kgcZ8lv7DfsiZuYx8KCjCSf" alt="red">
 </div>

 <div class="contain__img red">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTuotUTsRgW-MMvhKc1ZwyDQoamkTut4u-V0_h0bCbxAWMl36A9Xg" alt="red">
 </div>

 <div class="contain__img red">
    <img class="img" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3823/11294769684_5d4b0d1a23_n.jpg" alt="red">
 </div>

 <div class="contain__img blue">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27" alt="blue">
 </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#mainLink a').on('click', function(){
 var cls = $(this).prop('id');
 if(cls == 'all') {
   $(".contain__img").show();
 } else {
 $(".contain__img").hide();
   $("."+cls).show();
 }
});
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('#mainLink a').on('click', function(){
   var cls = $(this).prop('id');
   if(cls == 'all') {
     $(".contain__img").show();
   } else {
     $(".contain__img").hide();
    $("."+cls).show();
   }
});
```

```css
.link__color {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.contain {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contain__img {
  margin: 15px;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link" id="mainLink">
  <a id="all" class="link__color" href="#">All</a>
  <a id="blue" class="link__color" href="#">Blue</a>
  <a id="red" class="link__color" href="#">Red</a>
</div>

<div class="contain">
  <div class="contain__img blue">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTn1if-yc-9w3onZhlF9j7eOJEbbH7NY9QoQ0wyuAy33WoH-ml" alt="blue">
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img red">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQFjKqjM52gBUsAisUgVSuGrPMi2kgcZ8lv7DfsiZuYx8KCjCSf" alt="red">
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img red">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTuotUTsRgW-MMvhKc1ZwyDQoamkTut4u-V0_h0bCbxAWMl36A9Xg" alt="red">
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img red">
    <img class="img" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3823/11294769684_5d4b0d1a23_n.jpg" alt="red">
  </div>
  
  <div class="contain__img blue">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27" alt="blue">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I don't want to have to use jquery.